# What's the difference between these two code snippets in Python

Tags: python-3.x, printing

In Python,

What's the difference between

```
print("Hello "+"There")
```

and

```
print("Hello","There")
```

The results seem to be identical but I suppose they are used in different contexts, could you please illuminate me?

Your regards, Ehsan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same result, slightly different ways to call the print function.

The first one computes a new string that is the concatenation of the two strings, then calls print with the single argument result.

The second one prints the first argument, prints the default separator character (space), then prints the second argument.  The separator can be overridden:

```
>>> print("Hello","There",sep='+')
Hello+There
```

You can see the difference in the disassembly as well.  Note that the Python byte code compiler figured out that the concatenation of two constants is a constant, and just generated byte code for the final constant.

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(lambda: print("Hello "+"There"))
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
              3 LOAD_CONST               3 ('Hello There')
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(lambda: print("Hello","There"))
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Hello')
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('There')
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            2 (2 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```